# How to ensure Foundation CSS Grid Blocks Load Left-Center-Right?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I cannot figure out how to edit the Foundation stylesheet so that the dynamically-added blocks shown in the attached picture load from left to right. Currently, they load right-left-center. Any help is *greatly* appreciated. Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Arqy8.jpg

```
    <div ng-repeat="(photo_id, photo) in photos" class="large-4 columns">
    <row>
        <div class="panel" data-photo-id="{{photo_id}}">

            <p>
                <img ng-src="{{photo.image_url}}" width="350" height="300"/>
            </p>
                <ul class="small-block-grid-4">
                    <li><button class="tiny button" onclick="#">Sleep</button></li>
                    <li><button class="tiny button" ng-click="setIgnore(photo_id)">Ignore</button></li>
                    <li><button class="tiny button" onclick="alert({{photo.camera_id}})">Info</button></li>
                    <li><button class="tiny alert button" ng-click="setAlert(photo_id)">Alert</button></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </row>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Foundation Docs for Grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html) say...

> In order to work around browsers' different rounding behaviors, Foundation will float the last column in a row to the right so the edge aligns. If your row doesn't have a count that adds up to 12 columns, you can tag the last column with a class of end in order to override that behavior.

For example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-3 columns">3</div>
  <div class="medium-3 columns">3</div>
  <div class="medium-3 columns">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-3 columns">3</div>
  <div class="medium-3 columns">3</div>
  <div class="medium-3 columns end">3 end</div>
</div>
```

In your case, Angular is automatically repeating your `div` elements with this line:

```
<div ng-repeat="(photo_id, photo) in photos" class="large-4 columns">
```

I don't have any experience with Angular so I don't know how you could make the last element different but I assume there is a way to do that, and hopefully this gives you a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Travis was spot on with the problem.

Your solution can be to add the `end` class to each column.

```
<div ng-repeat="(photo_id, photo) in photos" class="large-4 columns end">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
p img {
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-class`

```
<div ng-repeat="(photo_id, photo) in photos"
     class="large-4 columns"
     ng-class="{'end': $last}">
```